# Does Chu and Hough's solution to the mixing time of the 15-puzzle carry over to the Rubik's cube?

Tags: markov-chains, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, rubiks-cube

In his 1988 book **[Group Representations in Probability and Statistics](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4355560.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)** , Diaconis considers mixing times of the [15-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle).  He states:

> Here is a simplified version: Consider the blank as a $16$th block, and consider the puzzle on a "torus." ... It is not hard to show that it takes order $n^3$ steps to randomize a single square (on an $n\times n$ grid).  I presume that order $n^3\log n$ steps suffice to randomize everything. For a $4\times 4$, this gives about $90$ "moves" to randomize.  ...  Similar questions can be asked for **other puzzles such as Rubic's cube**. (page 90, § G(4). Emphasis added).

[Quanta magazine](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-calculate-how-randomness-creeps-in-20191112/) describes how recently Chu and Hough have [solved](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07106) Diaconis' version of the mixing time of the 15-puzzle by studying the eigenvalues of the corresponding transition (adjacency) matrix.  Chu and Hough showed that, contrary to Diaconis's conjecture, an $(n^2-1)$-puzzle takes $n^4\log n$ random steps to have a uniform probability of being in one of the $\frac{n!}{2}$ positions. I believe instead of only $90$ moves, it may take up to $4^4\log 4 \approx 355$ moves to sufficiently scramble the 15-puzzle.

Of course, both the the 140-year old 15-puzzle and the 40-year old Rubik's cube have had storied histories in mathematics and culture.  It's natural to ask:

> How much of the results of Chu and Hough carry over to address the mixing time of the $3\times 3$ Rubik's cube?  Under, say, the half-turn metric, or if easier under the quarter-turn metric?

Given that Chu and Hough's solution of the 15-puzzle mixing time is longer than the intuition of Diaconis, perhaps the mixing time of the Rubik's cube under the half-turn metric (quarter-turn metric) is much longer than the [diameter](https://www.cube20.org/) of $20$ ($26$).

Comment: It might be worth noting that even the previous incorrect conjecture from Diaconis is asymptotically larger than the diameter of the Cayley graph. http://ianparberry.com/pubs/saml.pdf indicates that the diameter is $\Theta(n^3)$ and that in fact almost all configurations are distance $\Theta(n^3)$ from a given configuration (e.g., from being solved).