# (How) does the spectral gap of the $n\times n$ Rubik's cube close with $n$?

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, cayley-graphs, adjacency-matrices, rubiks-cube

Consider the spectrum of the adjacency matrix $A$ of the Cayley graph of the standard, 3x3x3 Rubik's cube generated with the usual quarter-turn and half-turn twists of each face (the [Singmaster](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kubrick/kubrick/singmaster-moves.html) generators).  The Perron-Frobenius theorem posits that the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $A$ is one, and that the unique eigenvector corresponds to the uniform distribution over all scrambles or positions of the cube.  But the spectral gap - the difference to the next largest eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ - is, as far as I know, presently unknown.  This gap controls the mixing properties of the cube - *i.e.*, how fast the cube can be scrambled. A larger gap may correspond to a faster mixing.

Let us now ponder how the spectral gap of the generalized $n\times n\times n$ cube (under similarly generalized Singmaster moves) grows with $n$.  There may be a constant gap between $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1$ for all $n$, but if this gap vanishes as $n$ tends to infinity, we can say that the gap closes.   This growth rate with $n$ may be an interesting object to consider.

> Does the spectral gap of the adjacency matrix of the Cayley graph of the $n\times n \times n$ Rubik's cube tend to $0$ with $n$, and if so how quickly?

This is partly motivated because there are [lovely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlnUEknwdcI) [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MWTTiNhu7I) of people scrambling and then solving very large cubes ($n=15$ or $17$...). I suspect that their initial scrambles may be far from sufficient to randomly permute their respective cubes, however, as I guess that larger cubes are in general much harder to scramble than smaller cubes.  The number of Singmaster generators grows linearly with $n$, but the number of cubies/cells grows as $O(n^2)$.  How fast does the mixing time grow?  As $O(n^2)$, for example?

This is also partly motivated by curiosity about [Motzkin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1657) and [Fredkin spin chains](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09160), which are simple quantum many-body systems (QMBS's) with really nice combinatorial properties.  In both the QMBS problems and the Rubik's cube, finding the gap as $n$ go off to infinity corresponds to finding the [thermodynamic limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_limit).  Furthermore, the Motzkin and Fredkin chains violate the area law with respect to their entanglement entropy as their gap closes; does it make sense to ask about an area law for the Rubik's cube?

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but the number of "cubies/cells"
does not grow as $n^3$ because only the surface of the cube figures.
There are $6n^2$ stickers (and in most realizations all but $O(n)$ of them
come in equivalence classes of $4$).

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies D'oh!  thanks, and sorry for my carelessness.

Comment: Related MO question: [Does Chu and Hough's solution to the mixing time of the 15-puzzle carry over to the Rubik's cube?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/346106)